# Displaying similar colours to one selected in colour wheel

Tags: jquery

On a paint supplier website I am looking to allow users to click from a color. wheel, which will then display a number of paints associated with that color.

I'm wondering where I begin with this, as I'm not really sure. Would I be best using the jQuery color picker?

The closest functionality I can find (while not a wheel), is this - http://www.0to255.com/ - It doesn't necessarily have to be a wheel.

Thanks

Comment: Please read here the documentation on how to write a good question, your question is too broad and lacks any examples of attempts you have made yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This can;t be done only with jquery . you need to make relation with colors in database and then you can get  similar colors to selected one